# Is it possible to export a keyboard layout mapping for re-import onto another machine?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, boot-camp, export

I have an Apple wired-USB keyboard that I share with my MacBookPro and Windows 7 32bit Home desktop via a KVM (Keyboard,Video,Mouse) switch.

The MacBookPro has BootCamp for running Windows 7 64bit professional and I would like to export the key mappings for use on the Windows 7 desktop. The Windows 7 32 bit home desktop has some keys that don't map correctly such as backslash, and pound and hash sign. The Apple USB keyboard is a UK English.

I have seen tools such as "Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4"
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339
But this requires one to create a new keyboard mapping from scratch - it cannot seem to derive/auto-populate with the current mapping in use. I wanted to use a tool like this to export from the MacBookPro booted into Windows 7, for use on the Windows 7 desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MS Keyboard Layout Creator in this way. If you go to the "File" menu and then "Load Existing Keyboard..." it will present a list of all the keyboards known to the system. You can choose the mapping currently in use (or any other), and then from the "Project" menu, select "Build DLL and Setup Package", which will create a layout file you can use on another computer.